# Как заменить при выводе элементов массива переменных точки на запятые PHP

Tags: php, замена

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как заменить при выводе таблицы в двух столбцах row[7] и row[8] точки на запятые.

Дело в том, что при экспорте таблицы в Excel, у меня некоторые ячейки заменяются датами. Программистом себя назвать не могу, всё очень тяжко :) 
Пытался использовать str_replace, но или с синтаксисом проблемы или вообще не то делаю.

```html
if($result)
{
    echo '<table class="table" id="table2excel">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$row[0]</td>  <td>$row[1]</td>  <td>$row[2]</td>  <td>$row[3]</td> <td>$row[4]</td>  <td>$row[5]</td>  <td>$row[6]</td>  <td>$row[7]</td>  <td>! '$row[7] = str_replace('.', ',', $row[7])'</td>
        <td>$row[9]</td>  <td>$row[10]</td> <td>$row[11]</td>  <td>$row[12]</td>  <td>$row[13]</td>  <td>$row[14]</td>  <td>$row[15]</td> <td>$row[16]</td>
                                </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";     
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Вы вот это `$row[7] = str_replace('.', ',', $row[7])` делайте не внутри `echo`, а до него

Comment: А в какой момент это делать? Делаю "до", куда уже только не втыкал.. ничего не происходит.
Я забираю данные из базы, потом вывожу массив. Втыкал и сразу после запроса и перед echo, один фиг.

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: эм php не спарсит так перед эхо строку воткните и покажите вывод `var_dump($row[7])` в этом месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if($result) { 
?>
    <table class="table" id="table2excel">
<?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $row[7] = str_replace('.', ',', $row[7]);
        $row[8] = str_replace('.', ',', $row[8]);
?>
        <tr>
<?php 
        foreach($row as $value){ 
?>
            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
<?php 
        } 
?>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
    </table>
<?php
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Заработало!